# AggregateFunction vs simpleAggregateFunction in clickhouse

Tags: clickhouse

what is the different between AggregateFunction  vs simpleAggregateFunction and
aggergation state function?

Comment: look at this article [CLICKHOUSE AGGREGATE FUNCTIONS AND AGGREGATE STATE](https://altinity.com/blog/2017/7/10/clickhouse-aggregatefunctions-and-aggregatestate)

Comment: When possible prefer [SimpleAggregateFunction](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql-reference/data-types/simpleaggregatefunction/) because it *"stores current value of the aggregate function, and does not store its full state as AggregateFunction does"*.

Comment: @vladimir does SimpleAggregateFunction has pitfals(according to its store values)?

maybe need additional after aggregation, or something else?